# Clickable complex item in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, click

I have a grid control in my panorama app with some content and I wanted to be able to click on this grid to navigate to another page.
I've been searching for the best way for doing this, but I couldn't find any solutions.
I was thinking about templating a button to hold the grid with the image and texts, but I read somewhere that it wasn't a good idea, that the button wasn't good for doing this.
I also want to be able to use the tilt effect from silverlight toolkit.
Does anyone knows the best approach for doing this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with using a button for this; doing something like this is the reason Button is a ContentControl

All you have to do is make your Grid the content of the button:

```
<Button>
    <!-- Your Grid here -->
</Button>
```